# datasink(collect) still running in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I run a job on flink framework but the job still running at datasink(collect) stage with no output appears in the terminal or in the user-interface of flink, I used this command for running the job:

```
./bin/flink run -p 4 -q examples/gelly/flink-gelly-examples_*.jar --algorithm PageRank --input CSV --type integer --simplify directed --input_filename WikiTalk.txt --input_field_delimiter $'\t'     --output print
```

there is output in the log but in the web interface the bytes sent became 0 and no progress after that appears
such that

[it appears o in bytes sent column at the last row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ8bH.png)

I mentioned some of the screenshots to the web interface

[part of log data on jobmanager and it appears running datasink with no progress over the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5clQX.png)

[configuration of jobmanager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXYiI.png)

[configuration of taskmanagers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRlk0.png)

all of that on the flink-1.4.2 and if I used version flink 1.7.2 I got exception that refers to errors in the configurations.

Comment: What do you mean by "no output appears". Are there at least some log messages about the job submission, or is there really NOTHING happening?

Comment: Note that the output of the algorithm might not be shown in the terminal, but in the log/*.out files of the TaskManager.

Comment: yes there is output in the log but in the web interface the bytes send became 0 and no progress after that appears

Comment: Which bytes sent is 0 ? For which task?
Can you maybe post a screenshot of the Flink UI?

Comment: I edited the post  with some of the screenshots , could u take a look on them , thanks in advance